# C error: cannot convert 'pile {aka pp}' to 'pile** {aka pp**}

Tags: c

I'm getting this error no matter what I do: " 87    23  [Error] cannot convert 'pile {aka pp}' to 'pile** {aka pp**}' for argument '1' to 'void exercice11(pile**, pile**, pile*)' "

Here is the main program

```
 int main()
{    pile *p1, *p2, *p3;
     p1=NULL;
     p2=NULL;
     p3=NULL;
     int val=5;
     p1=empiler(p1,5);
     p1=empiler(p1,4);
     p1=empiler(p1,3);
     p1=empiler(p1,2);
     p1=empiler(p1,1);
     exercice11(*p1,*p2, p3);

     return 0;  
}
```

// "empiler" adds an element to the Pile, "depiler" deletes an element from the Pile, and "estvide" checks if the Pile is empty//

Here is the function that is causing the problem:

```
 void exercice11(pile* *p1, pile* *p2, pile* p3){
        int val;
        while(!estvide(*p1)){
            val = tete(*p1);
            if(!(val%2)) {
                *p2 = empiler(*p2, val);
        } 
            else {
                p3 = empiler(p3, val);
        }
            *p1 = depiler(*p1);         
    } 
        while(!estvide(p3)){
            *p2 = empiler(*p2, tete(p3));
             p3 = depiler(p3);
    }                
}
```

Here is the Pile structure :

```
 typedef struct pp
{ int val;
  struct pp * suivant;
} pile;
```

thank you very much for your time and help!

Comment: Think about the difference between the dereference operator `*` and the address-of operator `&`.

Comment: oh man, thanks! I didn't use C for a while and kind of forgot this stuff.

Comment: Each `*` in the type indicates one additional level of indirection, but each `*` operator in an expression _removes_ one level of indirection (by dereferencing the operand), whereas `&` adds one (by taking the address of its operand).